# Making Side Nav Fixed Scrolling

Tags: html, css

Help please - Sooo Im trying to make [this side nav](https://staging-shop.zgallerie.com/clp-furniture-2022) stay fixed when the content on the right scrolls down the page... similar to [CB's furniture page](https://www.crateandbarrel.com/furniture/). I'm not sure what else I need to add to the div to make it sticky or make it perform the way it does on CB.

Here's my CSS below:

```css
.leftSideNav {  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 32px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 260px;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.clpContent { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clpContainer {
  position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you create a simplified example of what you're trying to do, maybe in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) etc. to try and understand your problem? Then if you're still stuck, share that code here instead of simply linking to an external site that might change (which is not helpful for future users reading this question).

Something for you to look at is the CSS property `position: sticky;` combined with a `top` value. You can read about sticky positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I just added my CSS above. Basically, I need the left side nav to stay fixed when the right side (main content) is scrolling down... 

Sorry cant paste any HTML example into Codepen since this is being built through Shogun page builder and can only modify CSS and possibly some JS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I placed these in the wrong div

```css
position: sticky;
top: 120px;
```